# Dynamic default value of model field based on another field

Tags: python-2.7, django-models, django-orm

I want to add a new field to my existing model with default value as the field already present in the model.

**Existing Model** (just for example)

```
class Product(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127)
```

**Modified Model**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=127)
```

Here I am adding new field `full_name` and want value same as `name` field for all existing field.
After going through some solution, I got that we can define and call a method with default attribute, something like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=127, default=get_name)
```

but this gives an error:

```
ValueError: Could not find function dt_default in cater.models.
Please note that due to Python 2 limitations, you cannot serialize unbound method functions (e.g. a method declared and used in the same class body). Please move the function into the main module body to use migrations.
For more information, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#serializing-values
```

So then I defined this method outside the class, but then I am unable to access `self.name` as I don't have access to class instance then.

Anyone can please help me in the same will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have will lead to two columns with identical content in your database table, which looks like unneeded duplication. So the first question is why you need this?

If you need this just for displaying purposes, you can just define a method or a property in model class instead of adding a field, i.e.:

```
class Product(models.Model):

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(max_length=127)
```

This way in DB you will have only `name`, but you'll be able to access `full_name` attribute on `Product` instances:

`p = Product(name='Pr1')`

`p.name` will get you `"Pr1"`

`p.full_name` will get you `"Pr1"`.

If you are doing this in order to drop `name` field in future and then only use `full_name`, then I suggest you to look at [migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/) instead.

Also you can redefine `save()` method on the model and do the assignment of default there before calling superclass `save()`.

P.S. If you just getting started, it's not a bad idea to move from Python 2.7 to 3.5 and write your project with latest language features.

Also see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#migration-serializing about problem with method serialization in Python 2 and Python 3. Basiclybupdating to Python 3 will probably make your code work.

Comment: Actually the example shown above in question was just for explanation. You can suppose it as a way like I am having two columns in table named as `amount 1` and `amount 2` respectively and I need to add third column named `total_amount` in table with default value as sum of both column in each respective row.

Comment: Are you sure you need this? It's not the best DB design decision, unless you are absolutly sure it is needed to increase performance. It's redundant to store sum, when you can calculate it inside DB with built-in SQL function. And in Django, when making query, where you need this `total_amount` you can use `annotate` with `Sum` to add it to each object with `amount_1` and `amount_2` in QuerySet, and it will be calculated in DB, not in Python, so it will be relatively fast. Though, if you need to keep it - one way is to use the function as you did, but switch to Python 3, so that it worked.

Comment: Another way is to redefine `save()` in your model, though there're some drawbacks, like `save` is not called in some situations, though your function might not be called in that case either, refer to Django docs to find out more.

Comment: I am aware of annotation and aggregations, I have just given you an example to explain my question, and I know that we can do the same thing in python 3 but need solution for python 2.7.

Comment: I see, I'm just giving you my piece of advice. Anyway, IMO in your case look at redefining the `save()` method on the model https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods

Comment: yeah but `save()` method will be called while inserting new record, It will not update existing records.

Comment: To add it to existing models you'll have to create a migration.